# Android mapbox libs very big

Tags: android, maps, mapbox

I am using android mapbox SDK. Every thing works good. But my apk size is very huge. 
[image: mapbox]
[image: mapbox]

All of this folders contains mapbox libs for different android devices. How can i build app for only one android devices, like only for architecture x86  or armeabi;

Answer (score 2):

We've a document in our wiki that explains precisely that: [Strategies to reduce Android's APK size](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Strategies-to-reduce-Android-APK-size). I hope this helps.

We ship binary files for 6 architectures to make sure your app runs efficiently in a wide variety of devices, but thanks to ProGuard, ABI splitting, or the Google Play Store, you have tools to reduce the size of the resulting APK file.